# Actionbar missing when theme changes

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to change an app theme at run time so I have added the **android:theme** tag to my manifest file which changes it from Holo to Holo.Light and I works, the only thing is that the action bar isn't showing with the new theme

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing, thanks

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

[update] added the AppTheme as requested

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Paste your `@style/AppTheme` definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting ActionBar styles. You should extend base `Holo` or `Holo.Light` theme with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Comment: I mean with specifing `parent` as described in my answer. You are extending `Theme.Light` right now instead of `Theme.Holo.Light`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to change it at runtime? I'm going to have a theme option in a settings panel on my app